# What's the easiest way to enable a client to update files in a live site (without using CMS)?

Tags: ftp

Is there any site or software that facilitates the process of uploading files to a live site? (or using a FTP program like Filezilla is the only way to go?).

(and without using CMS)?

Comment: I guess I'm confused; are you looking for alternative protocols, client-based options, server-based options, or all or some of these together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a website context, you can use a content management system (CMS) such as Drupal to manage files (including uploading).

http://drupal.org/

And then there's PHP File Uploader:

http://phpfileuploader.com/default.html

There's also the WebDAV protocol, but it's not supported by a whole lot of software or websites; I use Dreamweaver, for instance, for uploading files to my work site.

Then there's SCP, for which you can use WinSCP (also for SFTP and FTP):

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/protocols